# Cryptocurrency Math

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, cryptography, applications, online-resources

I'm looking for any relevant books/articles on the maths of cryptocurrency transactions. Also open to any resources that may have some cryptocurrency transactions but not it may not be the main bite.

Mostly, I just want to dive deep into the maths of cryptocurrency by getting me hands dirty with some proofs (and/or applications, but preferably proofs).

Comment: Have you seen this? It is an explanation of the protocol and so may be a good place to start. http://www.michaelnielsen.org/ddi/how-the-bitcoin-protocol-actually-works/

Comment: There's a really good Princeton MOOC on Coursera that goes into some of the technical details. https://www.coursera.org/learn/cryptocurrency/home/welcome

Comment: @user4894 thank you! Wasn't looking for this but def gonna check out now. have you tried it?

Comment: Also, for anyone who sees this post later on, the coursea course contained a link to a textbook about bitcoin and crypto techs published by Princeton: https://d28rh4a8wq0iu5.cloudfront.net/bitcointech/readings/princeton_bitcoin_book.pdf

Comment: Is there actually any math behind cryptocurrency, I thought it was witchcraft and voodoo

Comment: Don't know why I can't post an answer but this is the Ethereum yellow paper that formally specifies the original version of the ethereum virtual machine and transactions https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf

Comment: And when you say 'maths of transactions' then at least in the Ethereum world you are looking at Elliptic Curve, diffie hellman, etc

Comment: Also, you will want to look at Cardano for a cryptocurrency system that fundamentally bases itself on academic review and formal proof. Their aim is to build a system that is rigorously analysed and provably sound (verifiable contracts etc) with the involvement of the academic community at every step, to avoid any unexpected nasty surprises, like what happend to the Ethereum with its DAO hack